# Non Archimedean field

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Prove that there exist an ordered field which is not complete but in which every cauchy sequence has a limit?
Here Completeness means every bounded above subset has a least upper bound.
And for cauchy sequence metric on ordered field we are talking is just like usual metric on R(set of real no.). Here also absolute value function has similar meaning as in R

Comment: I have tried field of rational functions with a order defined on it but i am stuck how to prove completeness. And if there is existential proof of this theorem(result), i don't know then.

Comment: You mean stuck on how to prove *incompleteness*? I think your question would be greatly improved if you added the example you are working on and an explanation of what you've proven and what you are trying to show.

Comment: Ok example I'll post soon. I am stuck in proving that every cauchy sequence has limit. I have already proved it is incomplete.

Comment: Ok this is link from where I have studied that:
Field of Rational function is ordered field without completeness. But I am stuck in proving that every cauchy sequence in this ordered field has a limit. http://www.math.ucla.edu/~hbe/resource/general/131a.3.06w/nonArchimedian.pdf

Comment: Ok the ordered field of rational functions is non archimedean but is not complete. But cauchy completion of this field is required non archimedean complete ordered field. Where completeness is cauchy completeness. And this we can prove every ordered field has cauchy completion.

Comment: @Sushil For Cauchy sequences to make sense, we need a metric on the field. So what metric are you using on the rational functions?

Comment: We define addition and multiplication as in polynomials. And order is defined as a rational function is positive if coefficient of highest order term in numerator and denominator have same sign. Then set of rational function is ordered field(as derived in link I shared).
Now about metric, metric is defined as in case of R usual metric. where absolute value of a rational function is as equal to that rational function if it is greater than 0 otherwise additive inverse of it. This is also explained in link.

Answer (score 1):

Every Cauchy sequence in the hyperreals is necessarily eventually constant by saturation.  Therefore the hyperreals are Cauchy-complete. On the other hand, there are bounded sets that do not have a least upper bound; for example the set of all infinitesimals.

Comment: Sorry not familiar with hyperreals. Can you please help me getting some references on hyperreal and result you have mentioned.

Comment: I would recommend the book by Goldblatt *Lectures on the hyperreals* see http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-0-387-98464-3